# umbraco change location of backend javascript

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I am having an issue with . in the path of files on a server and have tried everything I can to fix it. I need to get the site working again as fast as possible so I am trying to find out if I can make the back end look for the angular files in the 1.5.1 folder in a different location, while I try to fix the original problem.

For the original problem I have made sure urlscan has allow . in the path and followed this https://average-joe.info/allow-dots-in-url-iis/ but it has not helped.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you perhaps describe what has been done to introduce this problem in the first place, and why you need to move the location of the assets?

Comment: We could not find out what was the issues so we have moved it to a different server and that has fixed it.